# Looking to implement a scrolling gallery in my theme

Tags: gallery

I'd like to include a scrolling gallery in a theme I am developing.
Currently I have the code that "grabs" the attachments and place the thumbs inside a div (without using the gallery shortcode or anything)

I'd like to build a gallery that shows the thumbs scrolling below the content and the image to display above, aside with the content. I attach a image of the design
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI8kH.jpg)

I don't want to use NextGen or any plugin so, any help pointing me to a direction will be nice and very appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

Pick up a copy of [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) along with the [Gallery Field add-on](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/gallery-field/) and you should be able to customize on-page galleries to your heart's content. Just loop through the gallery and output the code to drive whatever JS based output solution you are pondering.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Wordpress related question but a Javascript one. Give a look at [Cycle2 jquery plugin.](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/)